# How can we initialize an array of type struct (which stores the json output) within a struct in golang

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct

I need to initialize the following data structure which will store a json. The Attack_plans will hold multiple plans and if I loop through the GeneratePlan struct, I need all the plans that were stored.

```
type GeneratePlan struct {
    Mode         string `json:"mode"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    Schema       string `json:"schema"`
    Version      string `json:"version"`
    Attack_plans []struct {
        Attack_plan *Attack_plan `json:"attack-plan"`
    } `json:"attack-plans"`
}
type Attack_plan struct {
    Attack_resources []struct {
        Attack_resource *Attack_resource `json:"attack-resource"`
    } `json:"attack-resources"`
}
```

Can anyone please suggest something? If the data structure needs to be simplified before initializing it, then please suggest that as well. I am very new to golang so please ignore the best practices to follow. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to make variables as a chain which will hold the values for all the structs. But then I got the error as "attackPlan is not a type and attackResource is not a type"
I realized that I cannot assign a variable of one type to another like above. These are the lines of code that I used,

plan := new(structs.GeneratePlan)

attackPlan := new(structs.Attack_plan)
 
attackPlans := []attackPlan //slice to store attack plan
 
attackResource := new(structs.Attack_resource)

attackResources := []attackResource

Comment: The two anonymous structs have a single field.  Do you need them for some reason? If so, rearrange the declarations to name all of the struct types.

Comment: @MellowMarmot
Can you please let me know how to do that? I need both of the structs as it will store the values from a JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! This simplifies the above data structure!

```
type GeneratePlan struct{
    Mode    string `json:"mode"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Schema  string `json:"schema"`
    Version string `json:"version"`
    Attack_plans []struct1 `json:"attack-plans"`

} 

type struct1 struct {
    Attack_plan Attack_plan `json:"attack-plan"`
}


type Attack_plan struct{
    Attack_resouces []struct2 `json:"attack-resources"`
}

type struct2 struct {
    Attack_resource Attack_resource `json:"attack-resource"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't u just json.marshal your object to a json string, you can got answer

Comment: Actually, the struct will output the values as JSON. I should have mentioned in the question. Apologies for that.
So I have a data structure from which I am fetching some values based upon certain conditions and storing the values in the above structs. I have the logic of how to fetch the values. I just need a way to initialize the above struct properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
generatePlan := GeneratePlan{
    Mode:    "mode",
    Name:    "name",
    Schema:  "sachema",
    Version: "version",
    Attack_plans: []struct {
        Attack_plan *Attack_plan `json:"attack-plan"`
    }{
        {Attack_plan: &Attack_plan{[]struct {
            Attack_resource *Attack_resource `json:"attack-resource"`
        }{
            {Attack_resource: new(Attack_resource)},
            {Attack_resource: new(Attack_resource)},
        }}},
        {Attack_plan: &Attack_plan{[]struct {
            Attack_resource *Attack_resource `json:"attack-resource"`
        }{
            {Attack_resource: new(Attack_resource)},
            {Attack_resource: new(Attack_resource)},
        }}},
    },
}
```

Comment: It is way too complex to use it. Do you know any way how can I simplify my struct? Like instead of nesting it how can I separate it to different structs?